# brew install gcc error

Tags: mysql, gcc, homebrew

I'm trying to install mysql using homebrew but when i run brew install mysql it says:

```
The Homebrew GCC was not installed.
You must:
brew install gcc
```

this is what i get when i run brew install gcc

```
==> Installing dependencies for gcc: gmp, mpfr, libmpc, pkg-config, isl, 
==> Installing gcc dependency: gmp
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/gmp-6.0.0a.
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gmp-6.0.0a.lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring gmp-6.0.0a.lion.bottle.tar.gz
sh: -L: invalid option
Usage:  sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
--debug
--debugger
--dump-po-strings
--dump-strings
--help
--init-file
--login
--noediting
--noprofile
--norc
--posix
--protected
--rcfile
--restricted
--verbose
--version
--wordexp
Shell options:
-irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option      (invocation only)
-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option
Error: Failure while executing:  -L /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmpxx.4.dylib
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
Error: The Homebrew GCC was not installed.
You must:
brew install gcc
```

hope someone can help me. I dont know what to do.

Comment: My first thing to try would be `brew install --build-from-source gmp`.  I suspect that the fact that you are running Lion might be part of the problem.